# Swap images from an array on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small problem trying to create a script that changes the images in the array. The main objective is to show 10 pictures when you click on the button. Clicking on the next button starts mixing all the 10 pictures and not leaving. It should be done without jQuery. Thanks for the advices.

HTML

```
<button value="show" id="Show">Show Images</button>
<button value="swap"  id="Swap" onclick="swapimg()">Swap Images</button>
<div id="image"></div>
<ul>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var buttons = document.querySelector('#Show');
buttons.addEventListener('click', add);
var img = ["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg","d.jpg","e.jpg","f.jpg","g.jpg","h.jpg","i.jpg","j.jpg"];
function add() {
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var img1 = document.createElement('img');
        img1.src=img[i];
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(img1);
        buttons.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function swapimg() {
    var myImage1 = new Array();
    myImage1[1] = "a.jpg";
    myImage1[2] = "b.jpg";
    myImage1[3] = "c.jpg";
    myImage1[4] = "d.jpg";
    myImage1[5] = "e.jpg";
    myImage1[6] = "f.jpg";
    myImage1[7] = "g.jpg";
    myImage1[8] = "h.jpg";
    myImage1[9] = "i.jpg";
    myImage1[10] = "j.jpg";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImage1.length);
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" 
  + myImage1[random] + "' alt='image'></img>";
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what is currently working and what is stopping you from achieving what you want. You got some code going, are you getting any errors? Where are you stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a random function that shuffle in every click to gives you a random array that could be used to generate rando images :

```
function swapimg() {
  var random = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].sort(function() {
    return .5 - Math.random();
  });

  ul.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    add(random[i]);
  }
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var buttons = document.querySelector('#Show');
buttons.addEventListener('click', addImg);
var img = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg", "d.jpg", "e.jpg", "f.jpg", "g.jpg", "h.jpg", "i.jpg", "j.jpg"];


function addImg() {
  ul.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    add(i);
  }
}

function add(i) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var img1 = document.createElement('img');
  img1.src = img[i];
  img1.alt = img[i];
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(img1);
  buttons.style.display = "none";
}

function swapimg() {
  var random = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].sort(function() {
    return .5 - Math.random();
  });

  ul.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    add(random[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button value="show" id="Show">Show Images</button>
<button value="swap" id="Swap" onclick="swapimg()">Swap Images</button>
<div id="image"></div>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works, thank you!! As I see, i forgot some functions to add :D Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not shuffling. With a random number, you could find that you have repeated images. I made something similar a couple of months ago. The following code shuffles a list. Hope it helps:

```
function shuffle(list) {
    if(list.length <= 1) return list;
    const first = list.splice(list.length/2);
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) return suffle(first).concat(shuffle(list));
    else return suffle(list).concat(suffle(first));
}
```

This code divides the list in half until you got only one element, and then it starts merging it again but with a 50% chance of swaping the given lists.